# Differences between requestIdleCallback and setImmediate?

Tags: javascript, timer

There are currently 2 different API's aimed at breaking tasks up into scheduled callback functions.

- [setImmediate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) (non-standard)
- [requestIdleCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback) (experimental)

To my knowledge there are no JavaScript runtimes (browser or Node) which currently implement both features.

I would like to better understand how the two features compare. I realize that `requestIdleCallback` has a `timeout` option which can be used to allow the browser to decide when to call it, and passes a `IdleDeadline` object to the callback where `setImmediate` passed any supplied arguments, but other than that how do these API's differ?

For example, are the following two examples functionally identical?

```
setImmediate(function() {
    // Do something.
});
```

```
requestIdleCallback(function() {
    // Do something.
}, {timeout: 0});
```

What about in the case where multiple callbacks are registered but the first one runs longer than the idle time?

Comment: I would think without `, {timeout: 0}` the two are as close to identical as you can hope for - as far as your last question - I doubt they are identical in functionality - but who cares about internet exploder and edge really

Comment: @JaromandaX You mean they are more-similar *without* `timeout: 0`? That seems counter-intuitive. Also, don't forget Node which only has `setImmediate`.

Comment: I would say `setImmediate` is really strange, if you want to be really `Immediate`, why not simply execute it?

Comment: re node - yeah, but you said `there are no browsers which currently implement both features` - which suggests you don't even care bout node - and lets face it, if the idea is to use the two methods as appropriate to achieve the same result in all browsers, what node does is irrelevant

Comment: @appleapple Yeah, the name is bad (don't know how that name was picked). I don't really want "immediate" so much as next-idle-time.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, perhaps it is more similar with `timeout:0` after all

Comment: There may also be an [`asap` proposal](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2014-09/sept-25.md#510-globalasap-for-enqueuing-a-microtask).

Comment: I think the problem is how a run time thinks it's *idle*. Is there a formal definition?

Comment: @appleapple Not sure about a "formal definition" but in a browser it would refer to the time in the event loop where it would otherwise have nothing to do.

Comment: I'm not sure. e.g. if a function would needs to be execute just at next frame, is it still *idle*?

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` will wait for a time to pass, then it will execute the callback.

`requestIdleCallback` will wait for the [main thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread) to be idle before executing the callback. Meaning that it won't slow animations, user can still click buttons and type into inputs.

How to choose between setTimeout and requestIdleCallback? setTimeout is best used when the callback must execute (Example: Sending data to an analytics server or logging out the user). requestIdleCallback is best for when you don't want to hurt the user experience in the cost of executing the callback (Example: Rerendering the DOM).

Keep in mind that requestIdleCallback is still experimental.

Comment: `requestIdleCallback` has no "wait this long before giving running the callback" parameter - which means the best is to combine the two for non-time-critical regular tasks?

Comment: If what you're saying is to use `setTimeout` to delay the execution, and then use `requestIdleCallback` to keep everything smooth, it seems legit to me.

Answer (score 0):

requestIdleCallback won't execute when `document.visibilityState === 'hidden'`, it will execute all callback at once when it become `visible`.

At least in electron's browser view.