# Is there a better alternative to setTimeOut(fn, 0)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback, settimeout

Is there another way of achieving the same behavior of scheduling a callback function on the JavaScript's [message queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#queue) to be run after the current [stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#stack) is empty?

In other words, is there a way, be it with `Promises` or third-party packages to push a callback to the [task queue](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=766) so that it runs after the current [stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#stack) is empty?

In other words, what are some equivalents/alternatives to passing `0` to `setTimeout` to take advantage of the asynchronous callback?

*Answers for all environments and all ECMAScript versions are welcome.*

Comment: Are you on a browser or node.js env?

Comment: @TusharShahi Both environments.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51757894/1048572

Answer (score 5):

In nodejs environment, you can do the async tasks in the following way.

Ref. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

```js
setImmediate(() => console.log("setImmediate"));
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Promise"));
process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick"));
console.log("sync");
```

Output:

```
sync
nextTick
Promise
setTimeout
setImmediate
```

In modern browswer, you can do the async tasks in the following way.

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Promise"));
console.log("sync");
```

Comment: Ironically, `setImmediate` is executed last. This is a good video about scheduling tasks BTW: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eHInw9_U8k

Answer (score 1):

Use [`queueMicrotask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask). It runs before control is returned to the event loop, so it will be scheduled to execute before `setTimeout(fn, 0)`.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout'), 0)
queueMicrotask(() => console.log('queueMicrotask'))
```

Output:

```
queueMicrotask
setTimeout
```

In terms of timing, `queueMicrotask(fn)` is equivalent to `Promise.resolve().then(fn)`, suggesting that `Promise`s are scheduled using `queueMicrotask`.