# Determine promise state using Promise.race and setImmediate

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout, setimmediate

**TL;DR**: Will already resolved promises *always* beat `setImmediate` in a race?

Background:

Sometimes you want to know if a promise is resolved without awaiting its completion. There are some old legacy tricks like using `util.inspect` to get the internal state and checking if it contains the string `"<pending>"`. However, a more stable solution is to use `Promise.race()` to essentially wait for your unknown promise with a (very small) timeout.

```
const p = doSomething();

const result = await Promise.race([
    p, 
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1))
]);

if (result) {
   // p was resolved within 1 ms!
   ...
}
```

This will at most wait 1 ms to get `result`, which will then either contain the resolved value of `p` or `undefined`.
If required, the "timeout promise" may of course return something different than `undefined` to distinguish actual `undefined` values returned from `doSomething()`:

```
const PENDING = Symbol.for('PENDING');
const result = await Promise.race([
    p, 
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(PENDING), 1))
]);

if (result !== PENDING) {
  ...
}
```

Now we'll either get the resolved value from `doSomething()` or the unique symbol `PENDING`.

**Now to my question.** In addition to `setTimeout`, there's a `setImmediate` function that basically behaves like a timer that expires immediately; it just gives the event loop a go before resolving. When using this in my `Promise.race` expression above, empirically it *seems* to work, i.e., if `p` is already resolved it will beat `setImmediate` in a race, but I'm wondering if there is any such *guarantee* - or if I should be using a timer of 1 ms to guarantee that a resolved promise beats the timer?

I've tried putting `p` before and after the `setImmediate` promise in the array passed to `Promise.race` and it worked both ways, but still I'm worried it might behave randomly or be OS dependent? Or is the fact that `setImmediate` waits for one round of I/O enough to guarantee that any resolved promises will win?

From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args):

> Schedules the "immediate" execution of the callback after I/O events' callbacks

Edit:

I found that even this "seems" to work:

```
const result = await Promise.race([p, new Promise(resolve => resolve(PENDING))]);
```

or actually even this:

```
const result = await Promise.race([p, Promise.resolve(PENDING)]);
```

However, here the order is important. If `p` is resolved and is before the timeout promise, it will win, but if it's after the timeout promise in the array it will lose.
The question is the same though: is this approach guaranteed to let `p` win if it's already resolved?

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68678528/14032355

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if it provides any evidence about how Promise.race() is guaranteed to behave.

Comment: The documentation say it. The Promise.race() method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Comment: Sure, but "as soon as one" is vague when the question is what happens if both are resolved.

Comment: The answer I mentioned in the comment above show you the sequence of the function executed by the event loop in nodejs and it explains which promise would be resolved first if they both executed at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the codes below in Nodejs

Ref. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

```js
setImmediate(() => console.log("setImmediate"));
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout"));
process.nextTick(() => console.log("nextTick"));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("Promise"));
console.log("sync");
```

Output:

You can notice the sequence and that's how it is executed in order.

```
sync
nextTick
Promise
setTimeout
setImmediate
```

To answer your question, we can wrap the codes in Promises like below:

```js
(async function main() {
  const result = await Promise.race([
    new Promise(resolve => resolve("sync")),
    new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(() => resolve("setImmediate"))),
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("setTimeout"))),
    new Promise(resolve => Promise.resolve().then(() => resolve("Promise"))),
    new Promise(resolve => process.nextTick(() => resolve("nextTick"))),
  ]);
  console.log({ result });
})();
```

As sync function is to be executed first, so it would be returned.

Output:

```
{ result: 'sync' }
```

You can comment one of the Promise above to see which one resolve first.